# Check if a coordinate lie in a Polygon

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I have a couple of coordinates in the Database that make up the following polygon, I want to check if a user requested/coordinates falls under this red area then it should return true, and if the requested/coordinates are outside this area, it should return false.

I'm using Laravel and Js at the backend and using google maps for this.
I just want to make an API that checks whether it lies in the current region or not.

[image: This image is about polygon area, I want to check if a request falls under the red region and return true]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check **turf.js** https://turfjs.org/ which is a spatial analysis library.

The method `turf.booleanPointInPolygon()` is exactly what you want.

https://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanPointInPolygon

From site documentation:

> Takes a Point and a Polygon or MultiPolygon and determines if the
>   point resides inside the polygon. The polygon can be convex or
>   concave. The function accounts for holes.

You just need to have your Point and Polygon in GeoJSON format (turf.js has also methods for converting to GeoJSON from other formats).

Comment: Thanks, it really helped. But as my Api was in Laravel so i had to make a call to js file which return the result set of it.
But it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I loved this problem! The answer is quite cool!

You need to figure out how many times the X axis cross the polygon. If the number is odd, it is inside your are, and if even, or zero, it is outside!

Here's a link describing it. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/